# Twig: How to round up?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, number-formatting

I have a division in twig. Sometimes, the result can be with decimals and i need to have always a rounded up result.

Ex.

```
7 / 2 = 3.5
```

I would like to have

```
7 / 2 = 4
```

I know how to use floor in twig:

```
7 / 2 | floor = 3
```

But this is rounding to the down digit, not to the upper one.

I know also that i can use number_format

```
7 / 2 | number_format(0, '.', ',') = 3
```

So this will also take the down digit.

Any idea on how to tell twig to take the upper digit ?

This can be done in a controller (Symfony), but I am looking for  the twig version.

Thank you.

Comment: This should definitely not belong to the view.

Comment: @moonwave99 What's the reason for that?

Comment: @Milos Because it’s logic. You just want to pass view data to your template to display it, not perform any calculations etc.

Comment: @MartinBean, yes looks logical. But why is then twig giving us a lot of possibilities: (calculations, logic) ?

Comment: You are tightly coupling some logic to the view - let it just display stuff, and wrap such logic inside your model: you'll end with reusable [and more readable] code. Twig has such functions because it is better to have them that not to, but you shouldn't be abusing them.

Comment: @moonwave99, Thank you for the information. Could you (or Martin) answer the question so I canaccept please.

Comment: @Milos I didn't answer actually ^^ I just pointed you to a different approach. I find Ferhad answer here below to be the best one, if I had to pick one.

Comment: Just because something gives you the ability to do something, doesn’t mean it’s right or you should. A knife gives me the ability to kill a man, but I just use it for chopping vegetables and suchlike instead.

Comment: Formatting numbers to be returned to the client definitely belongs to the view. The OP doesn't specify where the numbers come from.

Comment: @Maerlyn, the numbers are comming from the controller.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Update

On versions 1.15.0+, `round` filter is available.

```
{{ (7 / 2)|round(1, 'ceil') }}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/round.html

---

You can extend twig and write your custom functions as it is described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

And it will be something like this:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Twig/AcmeExtension.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;

class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'ceil' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'ceil'),
        );
    }

    public function ceil($number)
    {
        return ceil($number);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_extension';
    }
}
```

So you can you use it in twig:

```
(7 / 2) | ceil
```

Comment: Thank you, I have thinked about that and can be a good solution. Due to the moonwave99 and Martin Bean suggestions, I will do the logic on the controller side and use the template for only displaying results.

Comment: The round filter was added in Twig 1.15.0. The good answer is at the bottom of the page `{{ (7/2)|round(0, 'ceil') }}`

Answer (score 10):

New in version 1.15.0: The round filter was added in Twig 1.15.0.

Example: `{{ 42.55|round(1, 'ceil') }}`

The round filter takes two optional arguments; the first one specifies the precision (default is 0) and the second the rounding method (default is common)

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/round.html

Answer (score 4):

No idea how it is in previous versions, but in Symfony 2.2.1 you have to use parenthesis around your calculation (assuming you created the extension):

`(7 / 2)|ceil`

Apparently `7 / 2|ceil` is the same as `7 / (2|ceil)` since they both gave the same (wrong) result and only the above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `7 // 2`?

This [documentation page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#math) might be useful.

Comment: From the documentation, this is also taking the lower digit:  `20 // 7 = 2` and I need that  `20 // 2 = 3`

Comment: @Milos you are right. I think, there is no such filter integrated, but you can write your extension

Comment: yes, that's what the others told me. I will have to do that, or simply make the ceil on the controller side.

Answer (score 2):

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/round.html

Starting with Twig 1.15.0 you can use the 'round' filter and pass 'ceil' as the second parameter. The solution would look like this:

```
{{ (7 / 2)|round(0, 'ceil') }}
```

Formatting numbers for display definitely belongs to the view, not the controller. This would be considered display logic - which is different from the business logic in the controllers that should be kept as clean an minimal as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The round filter takes the first argument as the precision. So the correct formulation to answer the OP's question would be:

```
{{ (7 / 2)|round(0, 'ceil') }}
```

rather than

```
{{ (7 / 2)|round(1, 'ceil') }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/round.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 1.12.0 or newer, you can use the ternary operator and do something like this:

`{{ ((7 / 2) > (7 // 2)) ? (7 // 2) + 1 : (7 // 2) }}`

It's not so "elegant" but it works anyway.

Answer (score -5):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

use the ceiling function of the php to do what you want

Comment: As I mentioned: "This can be done in a controller (Symfony)" and I know that, but I am looking for twig only.